# How to: Create an onclick listener for ListView

Tags: android, json, android-studio, wamp

I've used a ListView to show my data from wamp server using mysql, also using JSON parsing , the following is my code....

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<PumpModel>> {

    @Override
    protected List<PumpModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJSON = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJSON);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            List<PumpModel> pumpModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                PumpModel pumpModel = new PumpModel();
                pumpModel.setPump(finalObject.getString("Pump"));
                pumpModel.setAvailable(finalObject.getString("Available"));
                pumpModelList.add(pumpModel);
            }
            return pumpModelList;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<PumpModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //TODO need to set the data to the list
        PumpAdapter adapter = new PumpAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
        lvPump.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}

public class PumpAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<PumpModel> pumpModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PumpAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<PumpModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        pumpModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
        }
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvPump;
        ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        tvPump = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPump);
        // Then later, when you want to display image
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(pumpModelList.get(position).getAvailable(), ivIcon); // Default options will be used
        tvPump.setText(pumpModelList.get(position).getPump());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Now I want to create an onclick listener for my list view, which can be used to open another activity, and show the Description of pumps in TextView.

Comment: I don't know why this question is getting so many downvotes and people are not even writing reasons.

Comment: your right@AmitUpadhyay these kind of down votes restrict the user to ask Question ,so please people avoid to putting down votes ,,its my request

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, where you defined your listview

you can write

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
//based on item add info to intent
startActivity(intent);

}


});

public ItemClicked getItem(int position){

return items.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, where you defined your listview

you write

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
ItemClicked item = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this,destinationActivity.class);
//based on item add info to intent
startActivity(intent);
}


});
```

in your adapter's getItem you write

```
public ItemClicked getItem(int position){
    return items.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement an `OnItemClickListener` (Best place to implement is in your adapter) & on your `ListView` object `setOnItemClickListener(yourItemClickListener);`

Refs : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener)